# Rails app and sqlite (dev) vs postgresql (prod)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I'm learning RoR and my development db is the default, sqlite and I'm deploying my app to Heroku which uses posgresql. I understand that to avoid such issues, I should develop with postgresql as well, and in future I intend to do this. However, I've got an issue that appears in production but not dev.

**Issue**: I've got a `User` and an `Account` model. A `User` can have many `Accounts`.

I made a migration so that when an `Account` is created, its `active` field is set to `true` by default.

```
class UpdateDefaultAccountActiveValue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default(:accounts, :active, true)
  end
end
```

This appears to work in dev.

In `/views/accounts/index.html.erb`, the following code outputs `true` or `false` depending on whether an account is active or not.

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <tr>
      <% if !(account.credit) %>
        <td><%= link_to account.name, history_url(id: account.id) %></td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= link_to account.name + ' (Credit)', history_url(id: account.id) %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= account.active %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

However, in production, the `/views/accounts/index.html.erb` doesn't output `true` or `false` depending on whether an account is active or not.

Why is this and how can I resolve this?

papertrail log:

```
2016-05-25T21:34:06.348465+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/accounts" for 176.248.123.34 at 2016-05-25 21:34:06 +0000

2016-05-25T21:34:06.355649+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AccountsController#index as HTML

2016-05-25T21:34:06.447420+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 64.5ms | ActiveRecord: 18.2ms)

2016-05-25T21:34:06.452111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts" host=???.herokuapp.com request_id=f33ab960-5c1b-4883-a28c-8c2b40388bad fwd="176.248.123.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=107ms status=200 bytes=4073
```

Comment: Could you show the logs (install papertrail addon from heroku if don't have it yet)? I guess the value is nil on the columns, so use the `$heroku run rails console` in terminal, find an account instance and check out the attr. If nil find all the instances of the class and set it true. Then add a `null: false` constraint to the db column with migration. Extra: change the order of the 2 options and use `<% if account.credit %>`. And you should change the development db to pg as soon as possible.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I've installed papertrail and it's attached to my app. How do I view the logs?

Comment: 2 ways: 1. from terminal: `$heroku logs --tail` 2. from papertrail: you just click on papertrail from heroku dashboard

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I've attached the log to the OP.

Comment: In the logs everything is fine as you get `200` status code. Have you checked the attr values of the boolean field?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Yes, there were nil values which I've now changed to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a model property when a record created, you must change it inside the model, if you run a migration, it will help with existing records only.

You need to add three lines of code to your model for it to work for new accounts created:

```
before_save do
 self.active = true
end
```

Comment: Sorry to rain on your parade but pretty much everything in this answer is wrong. If you set a default in the DB schema ActiveRecord will set it for new model instances. When you add or change a database default it only effects new rows / records. That callback would change `self.active = true` every time you update an account!

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve the exact issue that you are having but there is a far better way to add distinct states to a model than boolean flags.

[ActiveRecord::Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) lets create an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database.

```
class Account
  enum status: [:active, :closed, :supended] # basically whatever you want
end
```

---

```
Acount.active     # => Acount.where(status: :active)
acount.active!    # => Acount.update!(status: :active)
acount.active?    # => true
acount.closed?    # => false
acount.suspended? # => false
acount.status     # => "active"
```

Of course you need to add the integer column to the database:

```
rails g migration add_status_to_accounts status:integer:index
```

Don't migrate it yet! We also want to add a default:

```
class AddStatusToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :accounts, :status, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_index :accounts, :status
  end
end
```

- http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2012/10/10/booleans-are-baaaaaaaaaad/